# Is convergent $\int_0^{+\infty}\sin\log\left(\frac{f(x)}{xf'(x)}\right)dx$, if $f(x)$ is of slow increase in spirit of Jakimczuk's definition?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, improper-integrals

Let $f(x)$ of *slow increase* thus satisfying all requirements of Jakimczuk's **Definition 1** from [1] (it is a free access journal).

I wondered next question as a combination of previous requirements and definition and PROBLEMA 151, proposed in LA GACETA, [2] (in Spanish).

> **Question.** Can you prove that if being $f(x)$ a function satisfying Jakimczuk's definiton of functions of slow increase then the integral
>   $$\int_0^{+\infty}\sin\log\left(\frac{f(x)}{xf'(x)}\right)dx\tag{1}$$
>   is convergent? **Many thanks.**

Thus I think (I think that my question has mathematical meaning) that I am asking about if you can find a counterexample of a function that is of slow increase but being such that $(1)$ doesn't converge, or well that you can to provide me a proof of the statement written in previous question: *Let $f(x)$ a function being of slow increase (with Jakimczuk's requirements and definition). Then the integral* $(1)$ *is convergent.*

### References:

[1] Rafael Jakimczuk, *Functions of Slow Increase and Integer Sequences*, [Journal of Integer Sequences, Vol. 13 (2010)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/vol13.html) Article 10.1.1.

[2] *PROBLEMA 151*, proposed by Paolo Perfetti, La Gaceta de La Real Sociedad Matemática Española, Vol. 14, nº 2, p.285. The link PROBLEMAS Y SOLUCIONES, [here](http://gaceta.rsme.es/vernumero.php?id=82).

Comment: Have you tried to investigate that for a simple example of a function of slow increase? Do you have *any* reason to think the statement may be true?

Comment: Please make this question self contained and include Jakimczuk's definition

Comment: Many thanks @BrevanEllefsen to you and Professor Vector. I am going to think what should do I with this question.